# What is the most efficient way of switching to a new component within a Card?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How would I efficiently change to a new component within a card widget on a button press or something similar?

For example, if I have a Card component and a Form:

```
<Card>
   <Form> 
     ...
    <Button onClick={changeComponent}></Button>
     ...
   </Form>
</Card>
```

and when I click on that button, I want to change the component but keep it inside the same card while also passing through the information of that form:

```
<Card>
     ...
    <Typography>{form.text}</Typography>
     ...
</Card>
```

What's the best way to do this? Would it just be using conditional statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

```js
const [showText, setShowText] = useState(false);

function changeComponent() {
  setShowText(prevState => !prevState);
}

...

return (
  <Card>
    <Form> 
    { 
    showText ? 
      <Typography>{form.text}</Typography> : 
      <Typography>{'No text'}</Typography>
    }
     ...
    <Button onClick={changeComponent}></Button>
     ...
    </Form>
  </Card>
);
```